# The account does not exist in bugreport.apple.com

Tags: security, apple-id

I am about to file a bug, but I can not login...

When I open the url https://bugreport.apple.com, It asks me to login. OK, I tried my three different AppleIDs, and all of them give me the same error message: `The account does not exist.`. This is very awesome.

I CAN use the three AppleIDs to login icloud.com without any problems. So what can I do to login bugreport?

Comment: This is a security bug. A SSO (Single SIgn On, which is what the AppleID account is) account shouldn't be usable on an interface where you don't have an access . This is a like a hidden door.

Comment: I fixed my previous answer which brought you here  (no need for the `/web` component).

Comment: @danielAzuelos yeah, It's unbelievable that how you monitor all the questions and  replied me. I didn't expect you would reply my question. (hopefully my words make sense. My English is not that good.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a developer account which will be accessible with your actual account (AppleID):
[Apple Developer web](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It works. The error message is really NOT user-friendly, especially the link behind the login field is `Create yours now` which is an apple id creation form...

Comment: "really NOT user-friendly" is a very polite way of stating it .

Answer (score 0):

You have to enroll in Apple's Developer program at https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/.

Read and accept the agreement, enter your details, read and accept another agreement, and confirm your details. Do not pay the annual fee; instead, go to https://bugreport.apple.com/web/ and you should now be able to report bugs.